How to make Sankey Images in R?
that is the demo data
    data = structure(list(Species = c("Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", 
    "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", 
    "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", 
    "Cinachyrella", "Cinachyrella", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", 
    "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", 
    "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", 
    "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", "Mycale grandis", 
    "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", "U-1", 
    "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", 
    "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-2", "U-3", "U-3", "U-3", "U-3", "U-3", 
    "U-3", "U-3", "U-3", "U-5", "U-5", "U-5", "U-5", "U-5", "U-5", 
    "U-5", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6", "U-6"
    ), Method = c("Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", 
    "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", 
    "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-1", 
    "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", 
    "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-1", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-1", 
    "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-1", "Method-1", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", "Method-2", 
    "Method-2", "Method-2"), Component = c("Fiber", "Fragment", "PP", 
    "X0.200.µm", "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", 
    "Fiber", "Foam", "Fragment", "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", 
    "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", "PP", "X0.200.µm", "X1000.5000.µm", 
    "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", "Line", "PP", 
    "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "X200.500.µm", 
    "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", "X0.200.µm", "X1000.5000.µm", 
    "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", "PP", "X0.200.µm", 
    "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", 
    "X0.200.µm", "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", 
    "Fiber", "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", 
    "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "Fiber", "X1000.5000.µm", 
    "Fiber", "Fragment", "X1000.5000.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", 
    "Fiber", "X200.500.µm", "Fiber", "Fragment", "PP", "X0.200.µm", 
    "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm"), Total = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 18L, 1L, 1L, 12L, 4L, 4L, 12L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 7L, 3L, 2L, 
    7L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 13L, 1L, 1L, 8L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    3L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -72L))

I have used the code below to make sankey 5 layer sankey image
    library(networkD3)
    library(dplyr)
    
    # Map nodes for each stage
    nodes <- data.frame(name = unique(c(
      data$Species,               # Stage 1: Species
      data$Method,                # Stage 2: Methods
      c("Fragment", "Fiber", "Foam", "Line"),  # Stage 3: Shapes
      c("X0.200.µm", "X200.500.µm", "X500.1000.µm", "X1000.5000.µm"),  # Stage 4: Size ranges
      c("PP", "PE", "PS", "PET", "Rayon", "Cellulose", "Acrylic", "Resin", "Nylon", "PBS")  # Stage 5: Materials
    )))
    
    # Create links for all stages
    links <- bind_rows(
      # Stage 1 -> Stage 2
      data %>% mutate(source = match(Species, nodes$name) - 1, 
                      target = match(Method, nodes$name) - 1, 
                      value = Total) %>% 
        select(source, target, value),
      
      # Stage 2 -> Stage 3
      data %>% mutate(source = match(Method, nodes$name) - 1, 
                      target = match(Component, nodes$name) - 1, 
                      value = Total) %>% 
        select(source, target, value),
      
      # Stage 3 -> Stage 4
      data %>% filter(Component %in% c("Fragment", "Fiber", "Foam", "Line")) %>%
        mutate(source = match(Component, nodes$name) - 1, 
               target = match(
                 case_when(
                   Component == "Fragment" ~ "X0.200.µm",
                   Component == "Fiber" ~ "X200.500.µm",
                   Component == "Foam" ~ "X500.1000.µm",
                   Component == "Line" ~ "X1000.5000.µm"
                 ), nodes$name
               ) - 1, 
               value = Total) %>% 
        select(source, target, value),
      
      # Stage 4 -> Stage 5
      data %>% mutate(source = match(Component, nodes$name) - 1, 
                      target = match(
                        case_when(
                          Component %in% c("PP", "PE", "PS", "PET", "Rayon", 
                                           "Cellulose", "Acrylic", "Resin", "Nylon", "PBS") ~ Component
                        ), nodes$name
                      ) - 1, 
                      value = Total) %>% 
        select(source, target, value)
    )
    
    # Generate the Sankey diagram
    sankey <- sankeyNetwork(
      Links = links,
      Nodes = nodes,
      Source = "source",
      Target = "target",
      Value = "value",
      NodeID = "name",
      units = "Tons",
      fontSize = 12,
      nodeWidth = 30
    )
    
    sankey

but when use the sankey code the picture does not appear. This diagram will include five stages: Species, Method, Fragment/Fiber/Foam/Line (Stage 3), Size Range (Stage 4), and Material Type (Stage 5). Additionally, links will have consistent colors based on their source stages.

What happens if you run sankey or print(sankey)? Where is the code from?

Have you tried the ggalluvial package?

i don't know how execute 5 stages sankey in gg alluvial, could you help? i will acknowledge you.

You have NAs in the target column of your links data frame. For example, this works with your above data
sankeyNetwork(
  Links = filter(links, !is.na(target)),
  Nodes = nodes,
  Source = "source",
  Target = "target",
  Value = "value",
  NodeID = "name",
  units = "Tons",
  fontSize = 12,
  nodeWidth = 30
)


The NAs are introduced by this bit of code
# Stage 4 -> Stage 5
  data %>% mutate(source = match(Component, nodes$name) - 1, 
                  target = match(
                    case_when(
                      Component %in% c("PP", "PE", "PS", "PET", "Rayon", 
                                       "Cellulose", "Acrylic", "Resin", "Nylon", "PBS") ~ Component
                    ), nodes$name
                  ) - 1, 
                  value = Total) %>% 
    select(source, target, value)

You either need to rethink that bit, or possibly you want/need the values in data$Component to be included as nodes in the nodes data frame also.
